# Specifying Group for Bean Validation with SimpleFormController

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm working with an older spring project that's using the SimpleFormController. It was easy to switch in the beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator bean to look at the annotations on the command object, but I can't see how I would override one of the methods to enable the validator to look at a specified group of validation rules. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could conceivably write a spring `Validator` which thinly wraps the `javax.validation.Validator`, which would allow you to call the rules you would like; and just inject this into the controller.